# How to add hypen in between telephone numbers in android edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to add hyphen in between telephone numbers,in this format 123-456-7890 in android edittext.How can I achieve this.Kindly help me with a snippet.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String phoneNumber = "1234567890";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(phoneNumber)
                        .insert(4,"-")
                        .insert(8,"-");
String output = sb.toString();
Log.i("app", String.valueOf(output));
```

Output: `123-456-7890`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html) class for your requirement. This class will automatically format according to phone number.

```
public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private boolean isInAfterTextChanged;

    public synchronized void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
       if (!isInAfterTextChanged) {
           isInAfterTextChanged = true;

           // TODO format code goes here

           isInAfterTextChanged = false;
       }
    }
}
```